# What's wrong with my Snackbar?

Tags: android, android-snackbar

What's wrong with my Snackbar? I just have tried to have RED SnackBar, but somethong went wrong and it's color not RED... Here is my snackbar code and images to show its color and color i've tried to set... Help me please!

```
public void processException (String exceptionMessage) {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getActivityContent(), exceptionMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
        snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
        snackbar.show();
}
```

[My snackbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvA6G.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with `setBackgroundColor`, you can't just put in the id of the color, you need to actually return the value of the color you want to set, so:

```
snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red));
```

Answer (score 0):

in setBackgroundColor() you should pass color value instead of id

snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(YourActivity.this, R.color.red));